# Ruby on Rails cache: Is it possible to increase the expiration time for a cache fragment during the execution time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, caching

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I would like to increase the expiration time for a cache key during the execution time. I use *memcached*.

For example, I have

```
Rails.cache.write("key_test", "value_test", :expires_in => 10.seconds)
```

so that the `key_test` will expire in 10 seconds. In order to make available that key value for longer, **what I can do? Is it possible to increase only the `expires_in` without to set again the `value_test`?**

---

*The following code doesn't work*, but maybe I have to do something like this:

```
Rails.cache.write("key_test", :expires_in => 10.seconds)
```

Comment: What you can and can't do very much depends on WHAT cache backend you actually use. What Do you use?

Comment: @Mörre Sorry, I forgot that. I use memcached.

Comment: To change the expiration time you have to write the key/value again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work:

```
Rails.cache.write('key_test', Rails.cache.read('key_test'), :expires_in => 10.seconds)
```

Comment: Then it is like the cache is extended every time it is used. If I pass `expires_in` to `fetch`, is it also extended?